# Java okhttp3 How can I parse dynamic web content?

Tags: javascript, java, okhttp

When visiting a website with dynamic content, how do I get the  URL content that would appear in a browser after it has finished processing JavaScript?

For example, okcupid.com/visitors displays the names of users that most recently visited your profile.  Using okhttp3's standard request/response methods, the URL contents just has placeholders for where the the users name/picture should be.

*EDIT: I've added the that handles all requests in my project.  In general this coade handles requests with session cookie and access token without a hitch. It's only the contents of URL's that return dynamic content.

```
public void sendRequest(String URL, String method, String params) {
    okhttp3.Request request;
    if(method.equals("POST")) {
        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .build();
        request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                .url(URL)
                .post(formBody)
                .addHeader("Cookie", this.sessionCookie)
                .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.accountManager.accessToken)
                .build();
    } else {
        request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(URL)
                .get()
                .addHeader("Cookie", this.sessionCookie)
                .build();
    }
    try {
        this.response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        ResponseBody responseBody = this.response.body();
        this.contentsOfUrl = responseBody.string();

        try {
            if(this.sessionCookie.equals("")) {
                Headers headers = response.headers();
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
                    String headerKey = headers.name(i);
                    String headerValue = headers.value(i);
                    if (headerKey.equals("Set-Cookie")) {
                        if (headerValue.startsWith("session=")) {
                            this.sessionCookie = utils.findString(headerValue, "(session=[a-zA-Z0-9,%]+);", 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } finally {
            responseBody.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: We're unlikely to be able to help you without seeing more context. Could you post your actual code here and [describe what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Be sure also to check the [question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Sorry I thought that the question was basically enough that it wouldn't require the code.